# IPtables help forwarding port through WireGuard connection

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iptables

I have a home server behind a carrier-NAT so I cannot forward any ports to it. I have PLEX running (in a docker container) on the server and would like to access it from outside my home network. Therefore, I have hired a VPS (Amazon Lightsail) that, as was the idea, can act as WireGuard VPN to which I can connect the PLEX container.

I've attached a small overview of the situation (sorry for bad handwriting):

[image: small overview]

I would like

- the PLEX container to be both accessible through outside (through the public IP of the WireGuard VPS) and on my own network (through the local IP of the homeserver; the port is mapped to the docker container)
- to run WireGuard on the homeserver **in a docker container**, and attach the PLEX container to said WireGuard container
- the PLEX/WireGuard container to have the public IP of the WireGuard VPS - this is due to the fact that some PLEX clients will automatically try to connect to the IP that the PLEX server has/recognizes. It can't reach the PLEX server if this is the carrier-NAT IP of the homeserver. As far as I understand it, I **cannot** change this behaviour in the PLEX client/server

I am a bit stuck with getting all of this to work properly. As far as I understand, the configuration goes like this:

- forward the `WireGuardport` and the `PLEXport` to the VPS in the AWS settings
- uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` on the VPS to enable forwarding incoming requests at the VPS from `eth0` to `wg0`
- create `/etc/wirguard/wg0.conf` at the VPS with a `[INTERFACE]` and a `[PEER]` section
- create `wg0.conf`with a `[INTERFACE]` and a `[PEER]` section for the homeserver WireGuard docker container an drop it in the root of the `/config` folder
- setup `IPTABLES` rules at the VPS to actually route the `PLEXport` from `eth0` to `wg0` and back. This can be done by adding these rules in the `[Interface]` section of `/etc/wirguard/wg0.conf` at the VPS (correct? or do I need to do it in a terminal at the VPS?). **I need help with this, as I do not understand it completely and do not know/understand the syntax.** I *think* you also specify the WireGuard IP of the homeserver Wireguard+PLEX container here.
- setup `IPTABLES` rules at the homeserver Wireguard+PLEX container (in `wg0.conf`?) to make PLEX also reachable on the local network. **Again, I also need help with this**

I hope this explains the issue correctly; many thanks in advance for any help.